# Custom sorting array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects like so for example:

```
[ {
    id: '-1'
},
{
    id: '10'
},
{
    id: '1234'
},
{
    id: '1235'
},
{
    id: '-1'
} ]
```

I would like to sort this array so that it is ordered by the ids ascending (smallest to largest), however I would like objects that have the id of '-1' to be sent to the back of the array. So I tried this:

```js
const arr = [ { id: '-1' }, { id: '10'}, { id: '1234' }, { id: '1235' }, { id: '-1' } ]
arr.sort((a, b) => {
 if (parseInt(a.id) === -1 || parseInt(b.id) === -1) return 1;
 if (parseInt(a.id) - parseInt(b.id)) return -1;
});
console.log(arr);
```

As you can see from the snippet above it sorts them successfully ascending however it doesn't successfully move ids with '-1' to the back of the array.

Why does this happen? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why can't you sort in ascending order without worrying about -1. All the other numbers seem to be bigger than 0, so -1 will naturally be the smallest and gather at the start of the array? :)

Comment: @Max I'm more or less using this to sort data and display it. I don't explicitly want to sort smallest to biggest so that's why I didn't do that.

Comment: Ah, I also read "back of the array" as "begging" rather than "end"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How sorting works

First, let's take a look at what `.sort` expects you to feed it.

Given paramaters `(a, b)` -- we should return

- `< 0` if a < b
- `> 0` if a > b

## How you did the sorting

Let's take a look at your first line

```
if (parseInt(a.id) === -1 || parseInt(b.id) === -1) return 1;
```

`-1` means "a is smaller". But that might not be true. It might be that `a` (not `b`) is -1, and is bigger, yet we're always telling JavaScript to send `a` to the back when that's what we should be doing to `b`.

Instead, we want to return `-1` when `b` is -1, but `+1` when `a` is -1. It doesn't really matter what we return if they're both -1.

---

---

In JavaScript, any number except for `0` is truthful. Let's take a look at your next line.

```
if (parseInt(a.id) - parseInt(b.id)) return -1;
```

If `a - b` is 0, we don't return *anything* in this callback. If it isn't 0, we always say that a < b.

Notice that never do we say that b < a -- so if such an event were to occur, we couldn't handle it and would sort it incorrectly.

## How to sort correctly

### Fetch IDs

```
const aID = parseInt(a.id)
const bID = parseInt(b.id)
```

### Is `a` or `b` -1?

```
if(aID === -1) return +1;
if(bID === -1) return -1;
```

### Which is bigger, `a` or `b`

If you assume that `a` and `b` are *not* `-1`, then we can simply subtract `a - b`. Why? If `a` is bigger than `b`, then the subtraction will create a positive number to say b < a. If `a` is less than `b`, then the subtraction will create a negative number, to say a < b.

```
return aID - bID
```

### All together

```js
const arr = [ { id: '-1' }, { id: '10'}, { id: '1234' }, { id: '1235' }, { id: '-1' } ]
arr.sort((a, b) => {
 const [aID, bID] = [parseInt(a.id), parseInt(b.id)]
  if(aID === -1) return +1
  if(bID === -1) return -1
  return aID - bID
});
console.log(arr);
```

## Golfing

It might be helpful to make things shorter. Another answer, by [@Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz), helpfully showed a much shorter version. I thought it might be useful to explain why this works.

```
return (a.id === '-1') - (b.id === '-1') || a.id - b.id
```

#### What is `x || y`

`x || y` means:

- if `x` is truthful, return x.
- if `x` isn't truthful, return y.

#### What is `(aID === -1)`

This means `true` if aID is -1, and `false` otherwise

#### What is `(aID === -1) - (bID === -1)`

How can you subtract `true` and `false`? `true` will be interpreted as `1`, and `false` as `0`.

#### aID = -1, bID = not

This value will be `1 - 0`, or `+1`

#### aID = not, bID = -1

This value will be `0 - 1`, or `-1`

#### aID = -1, bID = -1

Remember, it doesn't matter what we return if the two values are the same

#### aID = not, bID = not

`0 - 0`. This is `0`. This is not a truthful value. So we go into the `||` bit. Which, in that answer, has the second bit be `aID - bID`, as described above. It's very clever and very short, though might not be as readable.

Comment: Thank you very much Max for the detailed answer! Learnt a lot from this :)

Comment: Thanks! I thought I'd add some information about the old accepted answer, in case you find that useful.

Answer (score 3):

You could take the function with a check for the items which should be sorted to bottom.

```js
var array = [{ id: '-1' }, { id: '10' }, { id: '1234' }, { id: '1235' }, { id: '-1' }];

array.sort((a, b) => (a.id === '-1') - (b.id === '-1') || a.id - b.id);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```